# [[extension]] how to get link address when hovered

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to get the whole link address, but with the `hoverProvider`, I can only get the part of hoverd range.

here is the `activate` code and the result

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
  // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated


  const disposal = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider("javascript", {
    provideHover(document, position, token) {
      const range = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position);
      const word = document.getText(range);
     
      return new vscode.Hover(
      
        word
      );
    },
  });

  context.subscriptions.push(disposal);
}
```

[image]

so how to get the whole link  'https://www.youtube.com'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/TextDocument.html#getWordRangeAtPosition), the `getWordRangeAtPosition` method allows you to define a custom word definition with a regular expression. A good regular expression to match a URL can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/13659134).

Thus, in your case, you'd simply have to add a regular expression to the `getWordRangeAtPosition` method:

```js
provideHover(document, position, token) {
    const URLregex = /(https?:\/\/)*[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    const range = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, URLregex);
    const word = document.getText(range);
    return new vscode.Hover(word);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I didn't realize the hover word is already split by the `word definition`, I thought it's the exact word